# SQL Server Express and SSRS Report Subscriptions - SQL Agent Service is not running

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, subscription, sql-agent

I am running SQL Server Express and am trying to set up email subscriptions for my SSRS reports. I cannot find documentation saying that these subscriptions are not supported in SQL Server Express, however when I attempt to set one up, I get a message saying

> The SQL Server Agent service is not running. This operation requires the SQL Agent service.

I know that SQL Server Agent is NOT supported in SQL Server Express, so I just want to confirm that, as a side effect of Express not supporting SQL Server Agent, that this implies that SSRS can therefore not support report subscriptions. Is that correct?

[image]

Comment: Correct - agent is needed to process the scheduled tasks

Comment: If I am honest, I would suggest that the statement "This operation require the SQL Agent service" was enough to tell you this. No SQL Agent, no Scheduling. You need at least Standard edition.

Comment: Developer Edition would also work, if your scenario meets the license terms.